# Chrome redraw error with sticky sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have been trying to implement a sticky sidebar navigation.

When scrolling and the sidebar has been set to sticky mode, it quickly goes up and down as if it tries to reposition itself. However, when I check the calculation being made and how it behaves in firefox this is not the issue.

Usually, I would just grab a plugin but this is a very specific use case, I do not know how large the sidebar will be in future.

Here is a link to the [gist](https://gist.github.com/JayyWalker/1ffb4f96437e0d64760f515167391e24)